# When reading rand.Reader may result in error?

Tags: go, random

Do I understand correctly that crypto/rand.Reader can return Read error **only** on platforms not listed below, i.e. when it is not actually implemented?

```
// Reader is a global, shared instance of a cryptographically
// strong pseudo-random generator.
//
// On Linux, Reader uses getrandom(2) if available, /dev/urandom otherwise.
// On OpenBSD, Reader uses getentropy(2).
// On other Unix-like systems, Reader reads from /dev/urandom.
// On Windows systems, Reader uses the CryptGenRandom API.
var Reader io.Reader
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**; `crypto/rand`'s `Read()` (and `Reader.Read()`) methods may fail due to a variety of reasons, even on the platforms listed as supported. **Do not** assume that calls to this functions will always succeed. **Always** check the `error` return value.

---

> Do I understand correctly that crypto/rand.Reader can return Read error only on platforms not listed below, i.e. when it is not actually implemented?

**No**. For example, have a look at the [Linux implementation](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand_linux.go) of `rand.Reader`. If available, this implementation will use the [`getrandom` Linux system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html), which may fail with a number of errors (most importantly, `EAGAIN`):

> `EAGAIN` - The requested entropy was not available, and `getrandom()` would
>                 have blocked if the `GRND_NONBLOCK` flag was not set.

The `EAGAIN` error quite literally tells you to "try again later"; the official meaning according to [`man 3 errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is *"Resource temporarily unavailable"*. So when receiving an `EAGAIN` error you could simply keep trying for a certain time.

If `getrandom` is not available, the `crypto/rand` module will try to open and read from `/dev/urandom` (see [source code](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand_unix.go)), which might also fail for any number of reasons. These errors might not necessarily be of temporary nature (for example, issues with file system permissions); if your application depends on the availability of random data, you should treat an error like any other kind of non-recoverable error in your application.

For these reasons, you should **not** assume that `rand.Read()` will always succeed on Linux/UNIX and  **always** check `rand.Read()`'s error return value.

Comment: Thanks  @helmbert. Do you know what should the program do when `rand.Reader.Read` fails and a randomly generated number is essential to proceed? Should it use another implementation, or just retry (when?), or something else?

Comment: An `EAGAIN` error quite literally tells you to "try again later"; the official meaning according to [`man 3 errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is *Resource temporarily unavailable*. So when receiving an `EAGAIN` error you could simply keep trying for a certain time. On the other hand, reading entropy from `/dev/urandom` could fail for any number of reasons that might not be temporary (filesystem permissions, etc.), which should be treated like any other kind of non-recoverable error (like, for instance, printing a reasonable error message and terminating the program).